# Modified git tag names and messages now being rejected because they already exist

Tags: git, git-tag

I came onto a project late and wanted to modify older git tag names and messages, so I updated according to several answers here on stackoverflow:

```
git tag newname oldname
git tag -d oldname
git push origin :refs/tags/oldname
git push --tags
```

That worked, changing the name, but I also wanted to modify the corresponding messages, so I then did this:

```
git tag newname newname -f -m "new message for renamed tag"
```

It appeared to work, when I viewed via:

```
git tag -n1
```

But, when I now try to `git push --tags`, I get the following error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://blah@blah/blah/repo-name.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote.
```

I'm not sure what to do now...

1) How do I fix this so that I retain the new names/messages and can push the tags without getting a failure?

2) What would have been a better method to do this in the first place?

thank you

Comment: try first to perform a full fetch `git fetch --all --prune` what are the results after that?

Comment: I tried `git fetch --all --prune`, although from what I can tell, that's for resolving issues with branches, when I'll looking at an issue with tags here.  when I `git tag -n1` after that I see the same seemingly correct list of tags and messages.  but if I try `git push --tags` again, I get the same failure message.

Comment: try to tag it like this: `git tag -a <tagname> -m <message>` so it will be an annotated tag instead

Comment: tried `git tag -a <tagname> -m <message>` and got this: `fatal: tag '<tagname>' already exists`

Comment: So you are trying to tag with existing name: use the `-fa`. flags on the same time, 


`git tag -af <tagname> -m <message>`

Comment: Thank you for your time.  That went better, using the `-af` flags.  Instead of a failure, I got `Updated tag '<tagname>' (was af7ce15)`.  My issue, however, is not that I can't update messages — I did that before as noted in my initial question, and I can view them via `git tag -n1` — but I'm not able to push the tags. The command `git push --tags` is still failing.

Comment: Do this - it will work and than ill summarize all into a full answer so you can accept it.
`git push --follow-tags`

Comment: Not sure if this adds any relevant information, but when I switch from master branch, where I did the tag updates, to another branch, I am able to `git tag -n1` and see all of the new names and messages for each tag.

Comment: I `git push --follow-tags` and got `Everything up-to-date` which seemed good.  But if I again `git push --tags` I get the same error/failure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110678/discussion-between-codewizard-and-david).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

Delete the tag on the remote, then push again to create it again (or use `--force` to do both in one step).

#### Discussion

The *idea* behind a tag is that it is a label that never changes (as opposed to the idea of a branch name, to be a label that *does* change).  As a result, Git is generally reluctant to take an existing tag and point it to a new, different place.

This is why you had to use the `-f` (force) flag when changing the tag:

> `git tag newname newname -f -m "new message for renamed tag"`

Without `-f`, Git would complain that the tag already existed, and do nothing.

Since you are using `-m`, you are getting *annotated tags*.  This matters because otherwise you would not be changing the tag in any way and there would be no problem.

#### Digression: plain vs annotated tags

I mentioned above that both branches (more specifically, branch *names*) and tags are labels.

A branch name like `master` normally points directly to some commit, by commit-ID.  Hence `master` is something you can read and translate into a commit-ID; the `git rev-parse` command does exactly that:

```
$ git rev-parse master
3ad15fd5e17bbb73fb1161ff4e9c3ed254d5b243
```

A tag name, however, can either point directly to a commit:

```
$ git tag temp-tag master
$ git rev-parse temp-tag
3ad15fd5e17bbb73fb1161ff4e9c3ed254d5b243
$ git tag -d temp-tag
```

This is called a *lightweight tag*.

Or, it can point to a newly created git *object* that represents a tag (called either a *tag object* or an *annotated tag object*, depending on who does the calling and how explicit they want to be).  A tag that contains a message, or that you create with `-a`, makes one of these *annotated tags*:

```
$ git tag -m foo temp-tag master
$ git rev-parse temp-tag
04565b0274c13ac49a70b8e34cdb9c912e02f0ab
```

Note that this annotated tag has a different ID from `master`.  It actually consists of a pair of items: a lightweight style tag, pointing to the annotated tag object in the repository; and the annotated tag object, pointing to the commit:

```
$ git cat-file -p temp-tag | sed 's/@/ /'
object 3ad15fd5e17bbb73fb1161ff4e9c3ed254d5b243
type commit
tag temp-tag
tagger Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1461965004 -0700

foo
$ git tag -d temp-tag
```

Note the `object` line, which contains the ID of the commit.

(Aside: try `git cat-file -p` on the raw IDs, including the commit IDs.  You will see things with `tree` IDs; try `git cat-file -p` on those, maybe piping through `less` or `more` since they may be fairly long.  Also, try running `git rev-parse` on the hash values, the `3ad15fd5e17bbb73fb1161ff4e9c3ed254d5b243` things, while shortening them, e.g., `git rev-parse 3ad15`.  All of these are quite instructive.)

Objects, once created, can never be changed—not a bit, not one single bit.  They can be removed entirely,<sup>1</sup> but not changed.  So, to move an annotated tag, you have to delete the old one and then create a new one, which gets a new, different hash ID.  The `--force` flag makes git do this in one step.

#### Back to the original problem

Since tags are not *supposed* to move, Git (now<sup>2</sup>) checks and makes sure they do not move.  To move an existing lightweight or annotated tag, you must use `--force` or `-f`.  In the case of a lightweight tag, this—at least in effect—deletes the tag (but not the commit) and then attaches a new tag of the same name to the new object.  In the case of an annotated tag, this deletes both the lightweight tag and the underlying annotated tag object, then creates a new underlying annotated tag object and attaches a new lightweight tag to the new annotated tag object.

You can, of course, split this up into the two separate steps, which makes it more obvious.

The same rules apply with `git push`.  Since `git push` has `--force` / `-f`, you can hide (and optimize) the two steps into one, but it's effectively a delete-and-re-create.

---

<sup>1</sup>Removing objects is actually fairly complicated.  Git is built around adding objects, not removing them.  The *garbage collector*, `git gc`—which internally consists of a bunch of separate scavenger phases, all of which you can run manually—is what really deletes stuff, eventually.

<sup>2</sup>In versions of Git before 1.8.2, `git push` applied the branch rules to tags, so you could push a tag if the operation was a fast-forward.  The 1.8.2 release notes begin with:

> "git push $there tag v1.2.3" used to allow replacing a tag v1.2.3
>   that already exists in the repository $there, if the rewritten tag
>   you are pushing points at a commit that is a descendant of a commit
>   that the old tag v1.2.3 points at.  This was found to be error prone
>   and starting with this release, any attempt to update an existing
>   ref under refs/tags/ hierarchy will fail, without "--force".

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of the different aspects of tags.  Unfortunately, while it got me past the `git push --tags` error/failure I was having, doing a `git push --tags -f`, or possibly one of the previous steps in this thread, somehow merged my v2.0 and v4.1 (first and latest tags set to point to most recent commit).  So, I deleted v2.0 tag and reset it to the proper commit it should have been tied to.  I think I'm good now after checking tags/messages via `git tag -n1` and tags and dates via `git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ai %d"`.  Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

The best way id not to delete the tag but simply to update the tag to a new commit.

```
# create a new annotated tag and force it to replace the old one
git tag -af <tagname> -m <message>
```

Now push the tags to the remote:

```
git push --follow-tags
```